# What's the cell limit of the importdata function in Google Sheets?

Tags: csv, google-sheets, import, limit, spreadsheet

I'm trying to import a .csv file into a Google Sheet, but keep getting the message "Error Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.".
When manually importing, I get 8498 rows and 112 columns.
When looking on forums, other users mentioned 2 million cells, which is more than double of the cells this import contains.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: 2M cells are just theoretical. most formulae will break around 50k of cells

Comment: What is the url you are using for this? Do you get this error solely with this url? If yes, can you confirm you are allowed to import any data from it?

Comment: I've tested with 2 files on our FTP server: https://images.hermie.com/uploads/upload/test1.csv and https://images.hermie.com/uploads/upload/test2.csv. The first one (small number of cells) is successful to import, the 2nd isn't (same amount as the original file).

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace importdata by this function

```
function importCsvFromIdv1() {
  var id = '_______id du fichier____________';
  var csv = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mySheet");
  sh.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

for instance, with test2.csv ... form A1 to DI8498

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, unfortunately I get a new error message when testing the new function: "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (regel 3)." I guess this isn't possible for this file because of FTP restrictions?

Comment: Yes, I confirm ... test after importing the csv file in your own drive !

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately this still doesn't work. I've added 2 files on the FTP (https://images.hermie.com/uploads/upload/test1.csv and https://images.hermie.com/uploads/upload/test2.csv) where the first file (small amount of cells) can be imported succesfully, the 2nd (same amount as the original csv file) can't.

Comment: it's a bit long, but it works on my side (I have added a screen shot in my answer corresponding to test2.csv)

Comment: Hi Mike, too bad it still doesn't work. I've added the file to my personal drive and gave read & write permissions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZdRCPjSDPImI154GWwsrVUp8X9YfstJN/view?usp=sharing. Then I created the script and added it to the first cell in the file "=importCsvFromIdv1()". Correct?

Comment: Lunch the script when you are situated in the script editor view.

Comment: I now got a new error: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp. importCsvFromIdv1 @ Code.gs:3. Do I have to put in the share link or the file name for the var id? I've tried both but keep getting this error.

Comment: try with `var id = '1yc04iLf20k6oVlwSMpWm-xythMPKJoBO';` I have shared your csv file from my own drive.

Comment: I've tested with the id you mentioned but get the message it exceeds the number of allowed cells (5000000).

Comment: here is my spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12UEtoonz9MTEH-cIzd5x61P2-pXYIOm5tnUq_WQyDq8/edit?usp=sharing , open the script editor and lunch the script, and wait ...

Comment: strange, any idea how come my function doesn't work? It's the same workflow.

Comment: I am not sure to understand : dis you fail ou did you sucess with my spreadsheet ?

Comment: Hi Mike; it worked with your spreadsheet and so I did the exact same steps on my account (also granted access) but still can't make it work

Comment: copy the spreadsheet, copy the csv file in your drive and test ! I have no more possibilities since it works on my side, very sorry !

Comment: No problem Mike, thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

in most cases you dont need whole importdata, just some part of it. if so, try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("url"); 5000; 20)
```

or:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA("url")); "where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work; I still get the error message even with 1;1 array°constrain :/

Answer (score 0):

The [following](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603) limits are displayed on Google's documentation about Spreadsheets on Drive:

> Spreadsheets
>
> Up to 5 million cells or 18,278 columns (column ZZZ) for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.
> Up to 5 million cells or 18,278 columns for spreadsheets imported from Microsoft Excel. The limits are the same for Excel and CSV imports.

Since you are mentioning you are not reaching any of the limits and that other spreadsheets from other domains with the same size seem to have no problems, you might want to contact Workspace Support directly by choosing one of the options [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).